# output of map task written to local file system?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

If output of map task written to local file system, what will happened if the input of map tasks is so big that output exhausts the written disk?

Answer (score 2):

The map task attempt will fail, and the task will be scheduled to run elsewhere. The cleanup for the failed attempt should remove the task files too.